# give ios simulator permission to access photo albums

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I've an iphone app where the user is able to upload photos. During test on ios simulator, everytime I click the "upload image" button, the simulator pops up an alert that says I should give the app permission to access photo albums.

The problem is that the simulator never asked me before if I want to give it access or not. And when I go to privacy settings on the simulator -> photos, I do no see the app to toggle it  ON!

I tried resetting content & settings of the simulator, but that didn't solve the problem.

I'm using xCode 5.0.2
Simulator 7.0 iOS 6.1 simulator component

Comment: When you click on the "upload image" button, are you calling `UIImagePickerController` somewhere?

Comment: I did reset the settings for location & privacy from inside the simulator, and that didn't solve it. The app still pops up an alert that I should give it permission, but it does not ask me if I want or not, and it does not show up on photo privacy either.

Comment: Calling AGImagePickerController

Answer (score 0):

did you check Settings->Privacy->Photos? you should allow your app have full access here.

Comment: If you read the question the OO states that this setting is already ON.

Comment: If i go there, I do not see the app to toggle it ON. It's just empty

Answer (score 0):

add following code to somewhere

```
UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

remember to add this function to handle picked image

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

try this then to see what happened on your machine.

Comment: Thanks alot Jerry, the problem was somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem

There is code

```
   if (status != ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please give the app access to photo album" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

[alert show]; }
```

I changed:

```
if (status != ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
```

to

```
if (status == ALAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
```

Then it worked and asked me for permission, accepted it, and everything is ok now

Thanks everyone